# No puedo ejecutar programa de Rust en Windows. ¿Como solucionarlo?

Tags: visual-studio, compilador, rust

Estoy tratando de compilar un programa de Rust con el comando en terminal `rustc holamundo.rs`. El programa en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hola mundo!");
}
```

Cuando intento compilarlo con el comando mencionado, me salta este error en la terminal:

```
error: linker `link.exe` not found
  |
  = note: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. (os error 2)

note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015, VS 2017 or VS 2019 was installed with the Visual C++ option

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Investigue sobre esto y encontré que la supuesta solución es instalar las [BuildTools de Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16). Yo instale por medio del instalador las de ARM64 y x86/64, ambas versión de VS 2019.

Toda mi búsqueda fue en vano, no encuentro solución, mi pregunta es: **¿Como soluciono este problema, que tengo que instalar para que el compilador funcione?**

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia, muchas gracias de antemano. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solución:**

Después de mucha búsqueda por una solución, me dí cuanta de que era MSVC. MSVC es una herramienta incluida en la carga de trabajo "Desarrollo para el escritorio con C++", que permite compilar código de C++. Esta es la que contiene `link.exe`, que era el archivo que no se encontraba.

Solo bastaba con modificar los paquetes instalados en el Visual Studio Installer, e instalar MSVC de dicha carga de trabajo.

**Resultado:**

Compilación:

```
rustc holamundo.rs
```

**Ejecución:**

```
Hola mundo!
```

Answer (score 1):

También me paso ese error y lo solucione instalando una de las herramientas para visual studio "Build Tools para Visual Studio 2019"
de la pagina de microsoft

1. Ingresas a la pagina https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/downloads
2. Descargas "Build Tools para Visual Studio 2019" e instalas
3. Reinicias tu ordenador
4. Corres el programa y listo.